# How to extract text from these colored images?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, tesseract, text-recognition

I want to extract the text on Labels from the images. The images are coloured and are in a real-life environment. PFA images. [Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqhtL.png)

I have tried multiple solutions:

1. I'm able to read text from flat images using Tesseract but it's not working if the text is at a certain angle.
2. Tried a lot of image pre-processing converting it to Binary and grayscale but not able to extract the required text.
3. Since the above step failed I was not able to de-skew the text either.

```
    image = cv2.imread("p18-73.png",0)
    thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image,255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11,2)
    coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh > 0))
    angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1]
```

The above pre-processing code is not working. Can you please tell me what is the best way to approach this image?

Comment: Use [google vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) API if you can afford it, there's also a free trial. It's cheap and simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the result of cv2.adaptiveThreshold()?
The result of cv2.adaptiveThreshold() is like this:

[image: Adaptive Threshold Result]

I think this is not what you want. 
Try to use global threshold cv2.threshold(), and adjust the threshold value.

```
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

[image: Global Threshold Result]

Also, you can add cv2.morphologyEx() to remove the noise.

```
kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
```